# What will be the effect of allowing fermentation temperature to drop on a nearly finished fermentation?

Tags: fermentation-temperature

I brewed this [Northern Brewer saison kit](http://www.northernbrewer.com/documentation/allgrain/AG-Saison.pdf) and picked the Wyeast 3724 belgian saison yeast.  Only later did I discover that this yeast has a tendency to stall out.  So as a preventative measure I started fermentation pretty warm (75F) and have been slowly knotching it up over the last two weeks (now at 85F).  My gravity is now down to 1.010 or so, and, wanting to save electricity, I was just going to remove the heater and controller.  The beer would drop to 75F.

Let's presume that the next reading I take 5 days after the last reading is the same.  What would be the difference if I maintained the temperature versus letting the temperature fall to 75F (upstairs)?  or to 65F(basement)?

Answer (score 3):

We'd have to see your recipe and know about your mash to be certain, but my guess is that the beer is done fermenting.  Assuming that's the case, dropping the temp to 75F would have no negative effect.

Comment: Denny, There's a link in the question to the recipe.

Comment: Thanks, Dale.  I rhink the beer is done, so dropping the temp shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Any theory to back-up the idea?  This beer is supposed to take 2 months instead of 1 to finish.  Will the yeast 'clean-up' as effectively at a lower temperature?